# How to create a table and insert in the same statement

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle and I'm struggling with this:

```
DECLARE 
 cnt NUMBER;

BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name like 'Newtable'; 
 IF(cnt=0) THEN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE Newtable ....etc';
 END IF;
 COMMIT;

 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM Newtable where id='something'
 IF (cnt=0) THEN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO Newtable ....etc';
 END IF;
END;
```

This keeps crashing and gives me the "PL/SQL: ORA-00942:table or view does not exist" on the insert-line. How can I avoid this? Or what am I doing wrong? I want these two statements (in reality it's a lot more of course) in a single transaction.

Comment: If you are getting error in insert statement, then most likely table has not been created in the above if condition. So check first your first if condition is true?

Comment: @Polppan It seems that oracle tries to validate the whole query first and then starts to execute. Of course at that specific moment the newtable does not exist yet and the insert statement is not valid. At least that is what I think is happening. If I execute this when the table already is created, then it's not problem. If I execute the two statements seperatly, they work fine. But not when I put them in the same transaction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't the `insert` that is the problem, it's the `select` two lines before. You have three statements within the block, not two. You're selecting from the same new table that doesn't exist yet. You've avoided that in the `insert` by making that dynamic, but you need to do the same for the select:

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Newtable where id='something']'
 INTO cnt;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a52e/1).

Creating a table at runtime seems wrong though. You said 'for safety issues the table can only exist if it's filled with the correct dataset', which doesn't entirely make sense to me - even if this block is creating and populating it in one go, anything that relies on it will fail or be invalidated until this runs. If this is part of the schema creation then making it dynamic doesn't seem to add much. You also said you wanted both to happen in one transaction, but the DDL will do an implicit commit, you can't roll back DDL, and your manual commit will start a new transaction for the insert(s) anyway. Perhaps you mean the inserts shouldn't happen if the table creation fails - but they would fail anyway, whether they're in the same block or not. It seems a bit odd, anyway.

Also, using `all_tables` for the check could still cause this to behave oddly. If that table exists in another schema, you `create` will be skipped, but you `select` and `insert` might still fail as they might not be able to see, or won't look for, the other schema version. Using `user_tables` or adding an `owner` check might be a bit safer.

Comment: I'm not using the all_tables of course, I have changed all the specific names in an attempt to make the whole thing more generic :). Altough are naming is getting silly sometimes, especially with our (partial) migration from sql to oracle and the limit of 30 chars our oraclenames have to undergo :).

I indeed ment that the insert shouldn't happen when the table creation fails, but without getting exceptions/errors raised.

It's not my idea to create them at runtime, atm it's the policy here (our database-migrations (several) are problematic atm...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach, i.e. create and insert are in two different blocks

```
DECLARE
    cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT  COUNT (*)
      INTO  cnt
      FROM  all_tables
     WHERE  table_name LIKE 'Newtable';

    IF (cnt = 0)
    THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE Newtable(c1 varchar2(256))';
    END IF;
END;

DECLARE
    cnt2    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT  COUNT (*)
      INTO  cnt2
      FROM  newtable
     WHERE  c1 = 'jack';

    IF (cnt2 = 0)
    THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO Newtable values(''jill'')';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but then it's not in one transaction anymore. That's my problem :). I'm picky (for safety reasons it should be one transaction, one rollback!)

Comment: @user2681745 Is there any specific reason for creating tables at runtime? A table is always something which is static. I am not sure what exactly are your requirements though.

Comment: Well for safety issues the table can only exist if it's filled with the correct dataset. And I have no idea to achieve that other then creating within the same statement. (ty btw for your help :))

Answer (score 0):

Oracle handles the execution of a block in two steps:

1. First it parses the block and compiles it in an internal representation (so called "P code")
2. It then runs the P code (it may be interpreted or compiled to machine code, depending on your architecture and Oracle version)

For compiling the code, Oracle must know the names (and the schema!) of the referenced tables. Your table doesn't exist yet, hence there is no schema and the code does not compile.

To your intention to create the tables in one big transaction: This will not work. Oracle always [implicitly commits the current transaction before and after a DDL statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm) (`create table`, `alter table`, `truncate table`(!) etc.). So after each `create table`, Oracle will commit the current transaction and starts a new one.